# Spring Roo Can't find dependent libraries

Tags: java, spring-roo

I'm having a really dumb problem with the standalone version of Roo. When I try and run it with `%ROO_HOME%\bin` added to my path, I get this:

```
C:\Users\Andy>roo
Error occurred during initialization of VM
Unable to load native library: Can't find dependent libraries
C:\Users\Andy>
```

Which seems really unhelpful to me. Is there any way to make the output a bit more verbose to see exactly what is missing? I have a non-standard location of anything due to having my OS on a small SSD, so I'm thinking that might be part of it, but it's kind of hard to tell what is going wrong with a message like "dependent libraries".

Thanks.

Comment: Looks more like a Java error; can you run `java -version` w/o errors?

Comment: Good call! It's not fixed yet, but if you want to put down an answer, I'll mark it correct. I did get the same error with `java -version`. Told you it was a dumb question! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This looks more like a Java issue rather than Roo proper.

Make sure you can run `java -version` (or any other `java` command) first.

Suspects include not setting a `JAVA_HOME`/`JDK_HOME`, a broken `PATH` environment variable, etc.

Answer (score 3):

> error occurred during initialization of VM 
>   Unable to load native library

This happens due to a java update version. Maybe you installed java 6 and its updates and after that you installed java 7 but before this you can not properly uninstall java 6 and all updates. So this problem arises.

But don't worry, we have solution for this. Go to

```
C:/Windows/System32/  .....
```

and delete from java and javaw.

Answer (score -1):

Backup the the `java` and `javaw` from your `C:/Windows/System32` in a seperate folder and try running the java command again. Hope this will fix the issue.

Comment: How do you know the user has a `java` command in that folder?